# How to execute Windows10's Bash command from PHP?

Tags: php, windows, bash

Windows 10 just released Anniversary Update today. Now you can use Ubuntu flavored bash command from Linux subsystem.

The question is: How to execute Windows10's Bash command from PHP?

I tried

```
<?php  
    exec('bash',$out1,$result1);
    exec('ls -l',$out2,$result2);
    var_dump($out1);
    var_dump($result1);
    var_dump($out2);
    var_dump($result2);
```

It doesn't work. All $out are empty array, and both $results are 1.
Any idea?

---

Just found out that I can run web server directly from subsystem.

e.g.

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2
$ sudo service apache2 start
```

Then put all web contents inside subsystem's directory located at %localappdata%\Lxss\rootfs

At this point I can execute bash script however I want.

Comment: Have you tried [shell_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)?

Comment: I did. It returns NULL

Answer (score 0):

You can not. Ubuntu on Windows is implemented as a different subsystem directly below the Windows Kernel. So it runs separate to normal Windows processes and can not interact with them. (At least that is how I understand it). But maybe you just have to use `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe` as the command.

Answer (score 0):

Bash is not meant to be used to run a server but you can run PHP-CLI on bash without an issue.

Instead of running the PHP script in Windows and then accessing bash it would be easier to create a command to run the PHP script directly in bash.

So you would run `bash.exe -c "php path/to/php-script.php"

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/10/19/interop-between-windows-and-bash/